# C# Constructor on type not found when loading Design

Tags: c#, constructor

I have some classes that inherited from another one. All those classes have a `Form` variable as an argument :

```
namespace ns_Controller
{
    public partial class MainForm : DockContent
    {
        private DocumentForm m_documentform;
        private ExplorerForm m_explorerform;
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            m_documentform = new DocumentForm(this);
            m_explorerform = new ExplorerForm(this);
        }
    }

    public partial class TemplateForm : DockContent
    {
        private MainForm mainForm = null;
        public TemplateForm(Form callingForm)
        {
            mainForm = callingForm as MainForm;
            InitializeComponent();
            //some code
        }
    }

    public partial class DocumentForm : TemplateForm
    {
        private MainForm mainForm = null;
        public DocumentForm (Form callingForm) : base(callingForm)
        {
            mainForm = callingForm as MainForm;       
            InitializeComponent();
            //some code
        }
    }

    public partial class ExplorerForm : TemplateForm
    {
        private MainForm mainForm = null;
        public ExplorerForm (Form callingForm) : base(callingForm)
        {
            mainForm = callingForm as MainForm;       
            InitializeComponent();
            //some code
        }
    }
}
```

I can build and run the code. Although, I cannot open the design (ExplorerForm.cs and DocumentForm.cs) as I got the error:

> Constructor on type 'ns_Controller.TemplateForm' not found.

Do you have any idea what could provoke this error? Is it OK to get the calling form like this?

Comment: I guess, that it should have default parameterless constructor to be displayed in designer, otherwise it can't find a constructor parameter to create a form instance in design time

Comment: Thank you @PavelAnikhouski, it works if I just add a paramerless constructor for TemplateForm.